# "Unexpected token" in a DB2 SQL statement that runs OK in Postgres

Tags: db2, db2-luw

I trying execute statement like following (i obfuscated it a little) in DB2:

```
UPDATE FIRSTTABLE SET fstatus=1 WHERE fid in (SELECT T.fid
  FROM FIRSTTABLE T
  INNER JOIN SECONDTABLE V ON V.efvid = T.efvid
  INNER JOIN OTHERTABLE E ON E.efid = V.efid
WHERE (efname = 'event')  AND  (eftname = 'eventhtml') FOR READ ONLY)
```

And receiving error:

```
42601][-104] An unexpected token "UPDATE FIRSTTABLE SET fstatus" was found following "BEGIN-OF-STATEMENT".  Expected tokens may include:  "<query_into_expr_top>".. SQLCODE=-104, SQLSTATE=42601, DRIVER=4.7.85
```

But, with, for example, postgresql this script works fine.
P.S. I am using DB2 Express, if it matters.

Comment: Which table is the `efname` from? Put the alias.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in the FOR READ ONLY statement. DB2 implicitly add's the same effect for all nested query's, and FOR READ ONLY makes it ambiguous. However, i dunno why i getting so strange error message.

Comment: The unexpected token is `FOR` I guess it is not allowed there.

Comment: The `READ ONLY` clause is not allowed in a sub-select, hence the syntax error.